# Showing the equivalence regarding non-degeneracy of a $C^{\ast}$-representation.

Tags: representation-theory, hilbert-spaces, c-star-algebras

> Let $\pi : A \longrightarrow \mathcal L (\mathcal H)$ be a representation of a $C^{\ast}$-algebra $A$ on a Hilbert space $\mathcal H.$ Show that $\pi$ is non-degenerate i.e. $\bigcap\limits_{a \in A} \text {ker}\ \pi (a) = \{0\}$ iff $\pi (A) \mathcal H$ is dense in $\mathcal H,$ where $\pi (A) \mathcal H$ is a subspace of $\mathcal H$ given by $$\pi (A) \mathcal H : = \text {span} \left \{\pi (a) h\ \big |\ a \in A, h \in \mathcal H \right \}.$$

This result is given as a remark in one of the [notes](https://documentcloud.adobe.com/link/review?uri=urn:aaid:scds:US:54149b00-ce87-3d16-91ab-6cd059ade052) (page no. $49$) I have found online but I am having hard time in proving this equivalence. Could anyone suggest something needful?

Warm Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest hint would be to prove that
$$\bigcap_{a\in A}\ker\pi(a)=(\pi(A)\mathcal H)^\perp.$$
Once you have this, prove both directions by proving their contrapositives.

Comment: Nice answer, but this question is definitely a duplicate.

Comment: It's elementary @Aweygan. Great answer. Kudos.